# Subfolders in App_GlobalResources (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, localization, resources, internationalization, globalization

Is it possible to put resource files (.resx) within subfolders inside App_GlobalResources?

For example:

> /App_GlobalResources/someresources/myfile.resx
>
> /App_GlobalResources/someresources/myfile.fr-fr.resx
>
> /App_GlobalResources/othereresources/otherfile.resx
>
> /App_GlobalResources/othereresources/otherfile.fr-fr.resx

Or, are all the .resx files placed directly inside App_GlobalResources?

If it is possible to use subfolders, how do you programmatically access resources within subfolders?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically, yes it is possible but there are some pitfalls. First, let me show you an example. Suppose my `App_GlobalResources` folder looks like so:

```
/App_GlobalResources
    /Test
        TestSubresource.resx
    TestResource.resx
```

Each resource file has a single entry called "TestString". I added each resource file using the Visual Studio menu so it created a class for me. By default, all classes added to the `App_GlobalResources` folder will have the same namespace of `Resource`. So, if I want to use the class generator and I want `Test` in the namespace, I need to go into the TestSubresource.Designer.cs file and manually change the namespace. Once I do that, I can do the following:

```
var rootResource = Resources.TestResource.TestString;
var subResource = Resources.Test.TestSubResource.TestString;
```

I can also reference them using `GetGlobalResourceObject`:

```
var rootResource = GetGlobalResourceObject( "TestResource", "TestString" );
var subResource1 = GetGlobalResourceObject( "TestSubresource", "TestString" );
```

Notice that I still use the "TestSubresource" as the means to reference the resources in that file even though it is in a subfolder. Now, one of the catches, is that all the files must be unique across all folders in `App_GlobalResources` or your project will throw a runtime error. If I add a resource named "TestResource.resx" to /Test, it will throw the following runtime error:

> The resource file '/App_GlobalResources/TestResource.resx' cannot be
>   used, as it conflicts with another file with the same name.).

This is true even if I change the namespace on the new resource.

So, in conclusion, yes it is possible, but you increase the odds of getting a runtime error because of two identically named resource files in different parts of the `App_GlobalResources` folder structure which is allowed by the file system but not by .NET.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. At least, I managed to do it.

Within a web site I added the App_GlobalResources folder. Inside it I created another folder "MyFolder" and placed MyResource.resx file inside. Resx file contained one pair MyKey1 - MyValue1.

Using the `GetResource` method of the following class I successfully extracted "MyValue1" for name="MyKey1"

```
static class Class1 {

    static Assembly FindGlobalResAssembly() {
        foreach(Assembly asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()) {
            if(asm.FullName.StartsWith("App_GlobalResources."))
                return asm;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static object GetResource(string name) {
        Assembly asm = FindGlobalResAssembly();
        if(asm == null)
            return null;
        return new ResourceManager("Resources.MyResource", asm).GetObject(name);
    }

}
```

This approach works in Medium trust also.

It seems that folders make no difference when accessing resources from code.